# How to change back button in material design?

Tags: android, material-design, android-support-library, android-toolbar, android-appcompat

In past to replace back icon at the action bar by a new one we use this aatribute in styles:

```
<item name="android:homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/up_indicator</item>
```

But similar approach with toolbar doesn't work:

```
 <style name="Toolbar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar">
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="title">@null</item>
        <item name="homeAsUpIndicator">@null</item>
 </style>
```

Do you have solution for this or can you share a link to source code with this styles? I don't find it by myslef. Al help will be appreciated

Comment: Look at this sample project: https://github.com/greenhalolabs/lollipopsamples Hope it helps

Comment: It doesn't contains custom back btn, it is just an example of new toolbar with navdrawer (actually it is bad one - nad drawer should overlap toolbar by guidelines). ANyway thank you for trying to help!

Answer (score 0):

To change the back icon in `Toolbar` using the styles, you can use something like this in your **app theme**:

```
   <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
       <item name="homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/up_indicator</item>
    </style>
```

Programmatically you can use:

- With a `Toolbar`:

```
Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.xxx);
toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.xxxx4);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

- with an `ActionBar` you can use:

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.xxx);
```

Comment: As I mentioned in my post this approach doesn't work. I have tried aith and without "android:" prefix. Toolbar use as action bar  Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        if (toolbar != null) {
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

Comment: In your question you are using @style/Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar, while I am using a style Theme.AppCompat.Light to be applied to the Activity.

Comment: Sorry, copy-paste typo. I use Theme.AppCompat.Light" as well and issue still exist